# Write a program reads in a series of passwords into an array&Store 10 passwords.After, have the reader enter a password & see if it is in the array.

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class  Password
    {
        public static void main (String [] args)
        { 
            {String [] myArray = new String[10]; 
                int i; 
                System.out.println("Enter a password: "); 
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
                String myString = in.next(); 
      //my arrays are here//
                myArray[0] = "password"; 
                myArray[1] = "password1"; 
                myArray[2] = "iloveyou"; 
                myArray[3] = "abc123"; 
                myArray[4] = "abc1234"; 
                myArray[5] = "bears55"; 
                myArray[6] = "shelby27"; 
                myArray[7] = "Mjcheer38"; 
                myArray[8] = "sillypineapple"; 
                myArray[9] = "freshvase"; 
    //not sure if this is where this  for loop should go//

                for (i=0;i<9;i++) 
                { 
                    if (myString.equals(myArray[i]))
                    { 
                        System.out.println("Password Accepted"); 
                        break;
                    } 
                    else
                    { 
                        System.out.println("Password Rejected"); 
                        break; 
                    } 
//I think my if statements are right....//

                } 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

The full question is: 6.    Write a program reads in a series of passwords into an array.  Store 10 passwords.  After creating the password array, have the reader enter a password and see if it is in the array.  If it is there, print “Valid password” and if it is not there, print “Invalid password”. I have no idea what I could be doing wrong. For the first password, it says accepted, but for the rest it says rejected. Can someone please point out where I have gone wrong. I cannot seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you don't want to immediately `break` out of the loop; that defeats the purpose of the loop entirely.

Including a `break;` statement in every possible execution branch of the for loop (i.e. it's impossible for `break;` *not* to execute) will ensure that the loop body will never execute multiple times. It won't be much of a loop, then.

Try turning your for loop into this:

```
boolean validPassword = true;

for (i=0;i<9;i++) { 
    if (myString.equals(myArray[i])) { 
        System.out.println("Invalid password");
        validPassword = false;
        break;
    } 
} 

if(validPassword) {
    System.out.println("Valid password");
}
```

Note that you only want to print "Valid password" if the user-entered string is not equal to ANY of the passwords in the array. Thus, printing "Valid password" and then "Invalid password" wouldn't be a good idea.

Comment: Got it! sorry, new to the site. :)